# Understanding the Path of SVG Images

Tags: svg

I am currently trying to understand the path function of SVG Images. I took a SVG from Wikipedia (map of the world, but everything is removed except for once little thing). This is the SVG Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   height="480"
   width="960"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg11"
   sodipodi:docname="map.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata17">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs15" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1002"
     id="namedview13"
     showgrid="false"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     inkscape:zoom="256"
     inkscape:cx="959.32356"
     inkscape:cy="478.85011"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="27"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg11" />
  <g
     id="g9"
     style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-linejoin:bevel"
     transform="matrix(2.0368307,0,0,2.0374975,-34.589547,-22.659498)">
    <use
       xlink:href="#a"
       id="use2"
       style="stroke-width:1.5"
       x="0"
       y="0"
       width="100%"
       height="100%" />
    <g
       id="a"
       style="fill:#ffffff">

      <path
         d="m 481.4,220 -1,3.2 7.3,-5.2 -2.1,-2.8 V 212 l -1.2,0.5 v 4.5 z"
         id="path6"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The only part I am currently interested in is:

```
  <path
     d="m 481.4,220 -1,3.2 7.3,-5.2 -2.1,-2.8 V 212 l -1.2,0.5 v 4.5 z"
     id="path6"
     inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
```

From what I understood, you need a command and parameters for the path. So the `m` would be "move relative to current cursor pos). The cursor is 0, 0, so it moved 0+481.4, 0+220, but after that there are just coordinates without a command. How are these to be interpreteted? Are these implicit `l` commands? For better unstanding, I am talking e.g. about `-1,3.2` after the move. What does these do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by @Mehdi is not quite correct.

If a command is repeated (ie. the same as the previous one) then it can be omitted.  So for example

```
L 1 2 L 3 4 L 5 6
```

can be abbreviated to

```
L 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

The exception is for `M` and `m`.  In those cases `L` and `l` are substituted respectively.

So in @Mehdi's example

```
d="m 481.4,220 -1,3.2"
```

is actually equivalent to

```
d="m 481.4,220 l -1,3.2"
```

The definitive source for answers to questions like these is the [Paths section of the SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/single-page.html#chapter-paths)